# Git - Retrieve contents of a specific directory

Tags: git

I have the following directories in my git repository.

```
home
client
server
```

I want to overwrite my changes in my `home` directory with the corresponding content in the repository. It should not affect the other two directories.

I tried to use `git pull origin master home`, and `git checkout origin/master home`. But none is doing what I need to do.

Answer (score 1):

Git was not designed to allow you to have a checkout of different commits in different directories (unlike Subversion). Git considers your project as a whole.

If you need to temporarily get one version for `home/` and another version for the rest of your project, you can use

```
git checkout <commit-id> -- home/
```

(Warning: erases all changes in `home/`)

But the next commit you make will consider changes from your working tree to the base commit for the whole project, hence would consider what you have checked-out in `home/` as changes, and commit this. You probably don't want that.

If you really need to play with different versions for different directories, then you should consider splitting your repository into several [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: That did not help. However, I have completely reset my contents with the latest in repository